# Wordpress Plugin Jquery Conflict Issue

Tags: jquery, wordpress, conflict

I have created a wordpress plugin that uses JQuery timepicker, which works with the following code in place. However, this code also stops all default jquery operations working in the admin section. After some testing I have found that the turning point is:

```
wp_deregister_script( 'jquery' );
```

With this line in place the timepicker works, but the default admin operations do no. With this removed the admin works fine, but the timepicker does not.

Here is the the relevant bit of code:

```
add_action( 'admin_init', 'jquery_admin' );

function jquery_admin() {

    global $concatenate_scripts;

    $concatenate_scripts = false;
    wp_deregister_script( 'jquery' ); //this is the line
    wp_register_script('wp-jquery', 'http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js', false, '1.9.1');
    wp_enqueue_script('wp-jquery');
    wp_enqueue_script( 'wp-jquery', 'http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js' );
}
```

Any help to fix this is greatly appreciated. :)

---

As requested, the time picker I am using is http://trentrichardson.com/examples/timepicker/, with slider tabs which can be seen on the examples tab.

Comment: 1) Is there any reason you can't just use the default jQuery version included with WordPress? 2) Since you have deregistered `jquery`, have you tried calling the new version `jquery` instead of `wp-jquery`? 3) Are you sure that the existing wordpress admin JS is supported by version 1.9.1?

Comment: The default jquery in wordpress doesn't support timepicker. Took me ages to get it to work... I tried calling the new version jquery, but the timepicker does not work. I'm not sure that 1.9.1 supports the admin.

Comment: Show us your code. Which timepicker are you using? this one? http://jonthornton.github.io/jquery-timepicker/

Comment: I am using this time picker: http://trentrichardson.com/examples/timepicker/ with sliders which can be seen in the examples tab.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using http://trentrichardson.com/examples/timepicker/ in my ACF Date and Timepicker plugin, and I don't have any conflicts with WP jquery. Please see [input_admin_enqueue_scripts](https://github.com/soderlind/acf-field-date-time-picker/blob/master/date_time_picker-v4.php#L316)() in date_time_picker-v4.php (in a non ACF add-on, replace the acf-datepicker dependency with jquery-ui-datepicker).

Comment: Thank you for your input. I have looked at your plugin and attempted to apply the time picker to my plugin, to no avail. Your script appears to be a fair bit more advanced and I don't think I can apply it correctly.

Comment: Is your code available online? I can have a look and see if I can find the bug.

Comment: Thanks. I have uploaded the code here: https://github.com/StickyMedia/wp-add-date.